# Удаление или отключение слушателя у Scene JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Всем добрый день, хочу удалить или ещё лучше отключить на время определённый 
MouseListener, покажите пожалуйста как это делается.

Comment: `scene.setOnMouse<event_type>( null )`?

Comment: @AndreyM спасибо, ваш способ помог

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как есть метод `addEventHandler(type, listener)`, то есть еще и метод `removeEventHandler(type, listener)`. Соответственно, вам надо ваш лисенер сохранить в перменную и когда вы хотите - удалять его, когда хотите - добавлять.

Comment: В JavaFX такого нету.

Comment: @ProstoCoder поправил ответ.